# Asp.net ajax pagemethods not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I have a project that originally did not use ajax. Now I want to make the page ajax enabled. What I did already is Install the ajaxToolkit and replace the web.config content with another one from an ajax enabled web site. I added Script Manager:

```
<form id="Form1"  runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" />
```

my method in the .cs file looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] CheckRating(string[] details)
{
    string[] result = new string[] { "AAAAAAAAAAA", "" };
    return result;
}
```

my java script functions are:

```
 function someName() {

        var details = new Array();
        details[0] = $("#HiddenFieldUsername").val();
        details[1] = "5310005003117";
        PageMethods.CheckRating(details, ss1, ss2);
    }
    function ss1(result, userContext, methodName)
    {
        $("#user_rating").show();
        $("#user_rating_text").html("Error User ratinh");
        alert("Sorry");
    }
    function ss2(error, userContext, methodName) {
        $("#user_rating").show();
        $("#user_rating_text").html("Error User ratinh");
        alert("Sorry");
    }
```

The problem is when it gets here: PageMethods.CheckRating(details, ss1, ss2);
nothing happens. None of the code in ss1 or ss2 is executed... java scripts just stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, the following webform works perfectly fine for me:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    public static string[] CheckRating(string[] details)
    {
        string[] result = new string[] { "AAAAAAAAAAA", "" };
        return result;
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var details = new Array();
        details[0] = 'foo';
        details[1] = 'bar';
        PageMethods.CheckRating(details, ss1, ss2);

        function ss1(result, userContext, methodName) {
            alert(result[0]);
        }
        function ss2(error, userContext, methodName) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you could use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to see exactly what happens under the covers and the actual AJAX request that is being sent as well as the response.

Comment: It says:
Object doesn't support property or method 'CheckRating'

Comment: I just created a new Web Site in Visual Studio and copied the same code in it. It works now.